# Flask set local html as the src of the iframe

Tags: html, flask, iframe

I am trying to understand how to render an html inside another html using iframe and flask
I have tried using the`<iframe src="{% include 'status.html' %}" width="100%" height="100%" style="outline:none; border:none; top:5%;"></iframe>` way however the server is having a weird Not Found error `"GET /%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%20lang= HTTP/1.1" 404` 
I have also tried using another method, as well `<iframe src="{{ status }}" width="100%" height="100%" style="outline:none; border:none; top:5%;"></iframe>` and in the flask

```py
status_render = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'templates', 'status.html')

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template(
        "index.html",
        status=status_render
    )
```

Using the second method I am getting this error `"GET /home/dimitris/Documents/SmartHome/MobileApp/templates/status.html HTTP/1.1" 404` despite of the fact that the `status.html` does exist on the above path
I read online that it should be a a separate request which means another flask route, however I am not really sure that I am understanding how this should be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, html files can only be rendered by calls from within the function of the flask application.
Include this code within your .py application:

```
@app.route('/show_status')
def show():
    return render_template('status.html')
```

In your html file, render the file as follows:

```
<iframe src="{{ url_for('show_frame') }}"></iframe>
```

There is no need to pass arguments to the html index in the main () function:

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Funcionou para mim.
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but there is some problem is displaying any kind of static or predefined urls of html/image in flask.
In order to achieve the desired output, follow the below steps:

1. In the <iframe> tag, give a value that will be used as a route in app.py. For example, let say you need to display iframe in the index.html. Then create iframe tag in index.html as:

> <iframe src="/**statusRoute**" height="200", width="500">

2. Now create a route with the same name in the app.py as:

> @app.route('/**statusRoute**')
> def showStatus():
>
>   return flask.render_template('**status.html**')

3. Ensure that the status.html is present inside the **templates** folder.

This would render the **status.html** inside an iframe of the index.html page.